# Beautifulsoup - Submit form data

Tags: python, post, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to programmatically download (open) data from a website using BeautifulSoup.

The website is using a php form where you need to submit input data and then outputs the resulting links apparently within this form.

My approach was as follows

Step 1: post form data via request

Step 2: parse resulting links via BeautifulSoup

However, it seems like this is not working / I am doing wrong as the post method seems not to work and Step 2 is not even possible as no results are available.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_text_link(soup):
    'Returns list of links to individual legal texts'
    ergebnisse = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"einErgebnis"})
    if ergebnisse:
        links = [el.find("a",href=True).get("href") for el in ergebnisse]
    else:
        links = []
    return links

url = "https://www.justiz.nrw.de/BS/nrwe2/index.php#solrNrwe"

# Post specific day to get one day of data
params ={'von':'01.01.2018', 
     'bis': '31.12.2018',
     "absenden":"Suchen"} 
response = requests.post(url,data=params)
content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")

resultlinks_to_parse = get_text_link(soup) # is always an empty list
# proceed from here....
```

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong. I am not really familiar with request post. The form field for "bis" e.g. looks as follows:

`<input id="bis" type="text" name="bis" size="10" value="">`

If my approach is flawed I would appreaciate any hint how to deal with this kind of site.

Thanks!

Comment: At first glance, your dictionary does not contain comma (',') for separating 'bis' key. I doubt this solves your problem but clearly you need to fix this first.

Comment: This was actually only in this post. In my code it was in. So, yes your are right, that I needed to change (here) but that it does not fix my problem. Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found what is the issue in your requests.

My investigation give the following params was availables:

```
gerichtst:
yp:
gerichtsbarkeit:
gerichtsort:
entscheidungsart:
date:
von:    01.01.2018
bis:    31.12.2018
validFrom:
von2:
bis2:
aktenzeichen:
schlagwoerter:
q:
method: stem
qSize:  10
sortieren_nach: relevanz
absenden: Suchen
advanced_search: true
```

I think the `qsize` param is mandatory for your`POST` request
So, you have to replace your params by:

```
params = {
        'von':'01.01.2018',
        'bis': '31.12.2018',
        'absenden': 'Suchen',
        'qSize': 10
        }
```

Doing this, here are my results when I print `resultlinks_to_parse`

```
print(resultlinks_to_parse)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/lgs/detmold/lg_detmold/j2018/03_S_69_18_Urteil_20181031.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/10_Sa_1122_17_Urteil_20180126.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/13_TaBV_10_18_Beschluss_20181123.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/10_Sa_1810_17_Urteil_20180629.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/10_Sa_1811_17_Urteil_20180629.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/11_Sa_1196_17_Urteil_20180118.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/11_Sa_1775_17_Urteil_20180614.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/11_SaGa_9_18_Urteil_20180712.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/12_Sa_748_18_Urteil_20181009.html',
'http://www.justiz.nrw.de/nrwe/arbgs/hamm/lag_hamm/j2018/12_Sa_755_18_Urteil_20181106.html'
]
```

Comment: Yes! This is working. Thanks so much for your help! How did you find out about the available parameters. I am struggling to investigate these kind of things. Always operating on a blackbox then...

Comment: @FredMaster you are welcome. To display the parameters I just opened the 'network' tab in the developer console of my web browser (Firefox). Then I clicked on the right POST request and choose to display the 'parameters' tab in the details request part (on the right)